# create polygon from array list points - coordinate sequence?

Tags: java, gis, geotools

I have an array list with coordinates:

```
List<Coordinate>  coords;
```

I want to create a polygon based on these values.

I am trying:

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
Polygon polyg = geometryFactory.createPolygon(coords);
```

but it shows that it wants CoordinateSequence:

```
The method createPolygon(CoordinateSequence) in the type GeometryFactory is not applicable for the arguments (List<Coordinate>)
```

If I try to create a CoordinateSequence it shows a bucnh of methods and I am not sure how to proceed (or if sequence is needed anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array of points too.

See http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jts/geometry.html for an example.

Here is some sample code:

```
  ArrayList<Coordinate> points = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
  points.add(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
  ...  
  points.add(new Coordinate(lon, lat));
  ...
  //make sure to close the linear ring
  points.add(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
  poly = geometryFactory.createPolygon((Coordinate[]) points.toArray(new Coordinate[] {}));
  valid = poly.isValid();
```

Comment: You mean using `LinearRing`?After first converting `coords` from `List` to `Array`?And by `holes` we mean empty area inside the polygon?Thanks!

Comment: And in order to find out if a point lies in a polygon , I can simply use `point.within(polygon)`?

Comment: I think contains is the method you want, or commonly not disjoint is actually used.

Comment: Ok , I tried with `LinearRing` first and then I used `within` and it seems to work fine! (regarding the holes, we mean empty area inside the polygon area?)

Comment: holes are empty bits inside the polygon, which can contain polygons them selves

Comment: I am using this way to create polygon but I am not sure if built polygon is on earth surface or in a plane .

Comment: The Earth's surface is a plane in this context - JTS is always cartesian